# Protractor Locator for elements of same class for Links using href using typescript

Tags: typescript, css-selectors, protractor, href

I have html code where the class names are same, only href has different links.

what is the best way to find these links  using css, i have tried the below one:

```
test = element.all(by.css('.xyz')).get(1);
```

However when i run the code :

```
await browser.actions().mouseMove(await locators.test.getWebElement()).click().perform();
```

i get the error:

> Failed: Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 0, but there are only 0 elements that match locator By(css selector,  .xyz)

Comment: Can you share the html code pls?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the most appropriate locator method for you would be [cssContainingText](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.cssContainingText). It will allow you to find element using the css and some text like so

```
const test = element(by.cssContainingText('.xyz', 'linkText'));
await test.click();
```